# Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression. NextJS

Tags: reactjs, webpack, dom, next.js, web-component

### Mutation Observer with Webpack and Next.js - Bundle Loading Issue

I'm working on a project where I'm using a library in conjunction with Webpack to create web components. To dynamically load these components as needed, I've implemented an `index.js` file with a mutation observer. This observer is designed to trigger a function whenever elements are added or removed from the DOM. Subsequently, this function calls the appropriate bundle based on the element in use. The mutation observer relies on a function called `discover` to identify components that are currently not defined.

When `discover` encounters components that are not defined, it invokes the `register` function to load the corresponding bundle file. Additionally, the `discover` function is called separately to perform an initial check for custom components that may exist in the DOM but are not yet defined.

For testing purposes, I've created an `index.html` file in my web component project to evaluate the functionality of the `index.js` file, and it's working correctly in that environment.

However, when I proceed to publish the bundle files and `index.js` file, which contains the mutation observer code, and integrate them with Next.js, I encounter an issue. Specifically, the corresponding bundle is not being invoked when I attempt to use my web component within the Next.js project.

#### Code of `index.js`

```js
// Your code here
const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
  for (const { addedNodes } of mutations) {
    for (const node of addedNodes) {
      if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        discover(node);
      }
    }
  }
});

/**
 * Checks a node for undefined elements and attempts to register them.
 */
async function discover(root) {
  const rootTagName = root instanceof Element ? root.tagName.toLowerCase() : "";
  const rootIsCustomElement = rootTagName?.includes("-");
  const tags = [...root.querySelectorAll(":not(:defined)")]
    .map((el) => el.tagName.toLowerCase())
    .filter((tag) => tag.startsWith("pw-"));

  // If the root element is an undefined custom element, add it to the list
  if (rootIsCustomElement && !customElements.get(rootTagName)) {
    tags.push(rootTagName);
  }

  // Make the list unique
  const tagsToRegister = [...new Set(tags)];

  await Promise.allSettled(tagsToRegister.map((tagName) => register(tagName)));
}

/**
 * Registers an element by tag name.
 */
function register(tagName) {
  // button
  const tagWithoutPrefix = tagName.replace(/^pw-/i, "");
  const path = `../dist/${tagWithoutPrefix}.bundle.js`;

  // If the element is already defined, there's nothing more to do
  if (customElements.get(tagName)) {
    return Promise.resolve();
  }

  // Register it
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    import('../dist/shared.bundle.js');
    import(path)
      .then(() => {
        resolve();
        console.log("Custom Element added successfully")
      })
      .catch(() =>
        reject(new Error(`Unable to autoload <${tagName}> from ${path}`))
      );
  });
}

// Initial discovery
discover(document.body);

// Listen for new undefined elements
observer.observe(document.documentElement, { subtree: true, childList: true });
```

**Usage in NextJS**
**_app.js**

```
import {useEffect} from 'react'
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  useEffect(()=>{
    import("lit-lazy/loader/index");
  },[])
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

**index.js**

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Next - Lit - Lazy - Mutation</h1>
      <pw-form></pw-form>
    </>
  )
}
```

**Error/Warning**
*Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/lit-lazy/loader/index.js*